# Microsoft Access: Is there a way where I can export the Forms for people to key in, and the data will be updated in the tables?

Tags: ms-access

I have currently setup a form with various subforms that will update the respective tables in a single database.

However, I was wondering if there is a solution where I can have the form accessible to others outside of Access. In other words, does anyone perhaps have a solution for allowing different people to input their data into the form without directly accessing the database and potentially editing table data?

Comment: Simple answer, no. Access forms only work within access. You'll need to find an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. You can certainly use the free edition of Access and install that on each desktop if they don't have Access. And as a general rule, right before deployment you should compile your accDB application into an accDE (a compiled version of your application).

So, there are a good number of commercial applications written in Access that uses the above approach. However, YOU the developer then on startup would hide the navigation pane, perhaps provide a custom ribbon, or whatever. In other words, the UI, the forms, and the ability to say run reports all needs some forms and UI to be built by you. (the runtime does not for example provide the navigation pane. So, as long as you build a full working application in which the users really don't know much about Access, and don't care, then you should be ok.

This extra "polish" is of course lots of extra work - but that's the case for any application, including ones built in Access.

So, you can have each desktop install this free runtime edition of Access. They thus don't have to purchase MS-Access, but they will have to install the free Access Runtime. (or you can put together an installer that does the install of the Runtime for you). So, if you are going to view and use PDF's on your computer, then you need some kind of PDF viewer. If you going to use Word on your computer, then you need Word or some software installed for that purpose.

And if you going to deploy FoxPro, or even vb.net programs? Then again, the correct runtimes MUST be installed on each computer for that software to work. And lo and behold, this also applies to MS-Access. In fact, even for compiled VB6 programs, STILL require the VB6 runtime to be installed on each workstation.

The runtime system for MS-Access used to be a paid "add-on" feature. (quite expensive at one time). However, the MS-Access Runtime is now free, and is a free download from Microsoft. However, it does not come with an install wizard for your application. However, a good number of free installers such as Inno can be used. So that installer can do things like create a folder for the application, create a shortcut on your desktop with an icon, etc. So, like any application you install, there are often lots of things you need to do. You can also provide some instructions, but for users to manually have to create a folder, a shortcut on the desktop, etc. is often asking too much of them.

So from the install process, to how great of UI and user-friendly menus and forms you provide to the user? That's up to you, and as noted, that last extra part to make the application friendly often requires a lot of extra work.

As noted, setting up your application to look nice, have all the features built in nice forms, etc. can be a LOT of work. If your applcation say has a nice form for selecting what report to run, prompts for date ranges, etc., and menus and forms to navigate around the application WITHOUT the user requiring knowledge of MS-Access?

Then your application is in good shape, and can thus be distributed to each workstation - even those without a full paid version of MS-Access. However, the runtime of MS-Access is in effect a version of Access, and like installing any office program, it STILL a large install.

And of course this means using a split database. (front end application part, and then back end database ONLY part).

At one time, the Access Runtime was about 30 megs in size. Last time I looked, I think its around 200 megs, I have not looked close at latest 2016 Runtime.

So, at the end of the day, users will require the paid edition of MS-Access, or they can install + use the free Runtime edition of Access and then they can run your application when placed on those workstations. How well your application will work and run as runtime VERY much depends on how great of a job you have done already, and if you have nice prompt forms, etc., and made efforts to hide most of the Access built-in user interface (UI).

However, if most users do not need the whole application, and are to enter JUST some data, and not need to run all the fancy features of your application? Then perhaps for each user, maybe a web-based system for that data input, and then your MS-Access database also shares and runs from the same database. So, you might have a complex manufacturing and scheduling system built in Access. But, you might also want a customer to go on-line and enter just a bit of data, or approve a project or some such. So, they don't need the whole application, but just use of some small bits of the application.

I mean, why have staff phone up a customer to approve some project, then you fire up your application, and on a screen now enter some information to approve or change the status of the project when the customer "on-line" can do that simple task (and save you the time and efforts on the phone or by sending some email to that customer).

So, it really depends on what kind of data entry for those few forms, but often for that kind of work, you would use web-based, but still continue to run your complex desktop software with all the extra features, and reports etc. that only your internal staff require (but, still allowing customers to do some data entry for you, or to inquire or approve projects, etc. on-line).

So, for internal software, Access can be great. But, for just a few data entry forms for lots of people, then MS-Access is not ideal, since they will need to install that software on each of their desktops, and will also need that MS-Access Runtime to be installed.